# Setting up sales targets for individual Sales member and Teams,

Tags: custom-object, forecast, design

I want to set individual targets for each sales member and for teams for monthly, quarterly and yearly sales.

Is there anything natively available in SF for this?

I couldnt find anything in SF for this. I was thinking of creating a custom object to hold individual targets.

The fields being

```
Target __c : Object

user : lookup to user
StartDate : Date
EndDate : Date
Target : currency
Team name : a picklist??
```

I need to also assign targets to teams. What is the best way to do it? Should i have a another recordtype for teams, instead of user, have Team name in the page layout?

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

The forecast and Quota outofbox feature provided by sfdc should solve the requirement.

https://na9.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/user_quota.htm

The above link illustrates how to add Quota .

https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000Hj69EAC
https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HZK1EAO
https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000btk2EAA

The above ideas that i found may help you to resolve issues that you may encounter while setting forecast hirerachy.

https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HYoDEAW

There is other alternative in above link suggesting  creating a custom Opportunity Record Types and Page Layout called "Quota"

Comment: Would we be able to set targets for teams?

Comment: For teams unfortunately there is no way than 2nd method to build record types and pagelayouts.

Comment: Can you eloborate on the custom opportunity record types and page layouts.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of companies struggle to use the standard Forecasts tab effectively to manage targets / quotas and sales performance.

The alternative is to use a custom object to represent the target and have Opportunities link to that target automatically via code. If the Close Date changes, or the Opportunity Owner is modified, then the code 'unhooks' the Opportunity from that record and links to the new appropriate target record.

There are a number of variations around this solution including linking the Target record to Territories. Its also possible to have Product Family targets (at the sales person and / or company level) and have the Opportunity Product Line items link to target records based on Product Family.

I created a blog that describes the solution and how it is used by companies to answer the question, "[is my sales funnel big enough to meet my revenue target](http://garysmithpartnership.com/sales-funnel/)".

I also created a [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3L5-GXrdOk) which shows the solution in action.