# Has anyone done setting of targets and actuals using opportunity records

Tags: reporting, opportunity, record-type

On one of my earlier questions
[Setting up sales targets for individual Sales member and Teams,](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/setting-up-sales-targets-for-individual-sales-member-and-teams)
@mohit had provided with a link to a thread where SteveMo had suggested using opportunity records to set targets
https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HYoDEAW.

Has anyone tried this? i am clear of setting up the record type and page layout. But unsure of how its set to get monthly targets for individual users and groups/teams of users.

Should there be a quota record for each month for each user, should i be using the close date to check if the quota is set for which month? How do we set quotas for teams

Thanks in advance

Comment: In large part, this sounds like more of a business decision for management to decide rather than one of a programming issue. Its my recollection that there's an example of this type of reporting in either the platform fundamentals or the analytics workbook; mostly in the context of creating a dashboard to compare performance between salespeople. That might be a useful reference for you.